# C: How to get rid of conversion error?

Tags: c, gcc, casting

I have a project which uses gcc version 4.6.3, and I'm forced to compile with "-Wall -Werror -Wconversion".  The following simple example shows an error I can't get rid of:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
  uint32_t u = 0;
  char c = 1;

  u += c;
  return (int)u;
}
```

Compiling it with the above flags gives:

```
test.c:7:8: error: conversion to ‘uint32_t’ from ‘char’ may change the sign of the result [-Werror=sign-conversion]
```

Ok, fine.  Just add a typecast, right?  Nope.  Changing line 7 to `u += (uint32_t)c` does not make the error go away.  Even changing it to `u = u + (uint32_t)c` does not make it go away.

Is it possible to fix this?

Please note that the "char" is coming from a string, so I don't have the option to change its type.

Comment: The char is/could be signed (ie could have negative values) while an uint32_t can only have positive values. What would be your desired result if u were 0 and c were -1?

Comment: It's ASCII text in the string, so I know they're not negative values.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: There is no guarantee that `char` is signed or not. It could be either: it's implementation-defined, as per C99 6.2.5p15.

Comment: You have to consider encoding in the string. What type is the string? Is it UTF-8 or simple null-terminated string? This determines byte-width of single character

Comment: So you're adding a `char` to a `uint32_t` and then casting it to `int`? Why?

Comment: @netcoder: the cast to an int is contrived for the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles fine here:

```
u += (unsigned char)c;
```

This will only *silence the warning*, however — without doing anything to each `c` at run-time, unlike Basile's proposal.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is with signed (negative) character. You might try

```
 u += (unsigned) (c&0xff);
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is which conversion you want. If you want the conversion defined by the standard, you apparently need to assign `c` to a (temporary) `uint32_t` variable.

```
uint32_t temp = (uint32_t)c;
u += temp;
```

works as intended (at least with my gcc-4.6.2).

If that is not the intended conversion - but why would you then explicitly ask for it using `(uint32_t)c`? - the solutions suggested by Basile Starynkevich or Mikhail T., or the `-funsigned-char` flag would eliminate the warning.

IMO it's a (terrible) bug in gcc, and clang seems to agree, `u += (uint32_t)c;` works as intended there.